# Use R loop to load and append multiple files from AWS S3 bucket and save them as SQLite table

Tags: r, amazon-s3, tidyverse

Need help to create loop in R that reads multiple files from AWS S3 bucket, appends them and saves them in SQLite table.  I was appending each file individually when there were only 8 of them, but now there are over 1,000 and I need a loop to run through all the files.  Here is the code I used to use when I had only 8:

```
require(aws.s3)
require(data.table)
require(tidyverse)
require(rjson)
require(parallel)
require(DBI)

# Set Up SQLite -----------------------------------------------------------
datamart <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "datamart.sqlite")

# RM s3 bucket credentials ------------------------------------------------
Sys.setenv(
  "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID" = 'HIDDEN',
  "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY" = 'HIDDEN',
  "AWS_DEFAULT_REGION" = "us-east-1")
```

I would read the first file...

```
# Load policy files -------------------------------------------------------
tempfile <- tempfile()
save_object(object = "s3://thg_bucket/folder1/folder2/file.000", file = tempfile)
pol_temp <- read.csv(file = tempfile, sep = "|", quote = NULL) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ map_chr(.x, ~ str_sub(string = .x, start = 2, end = -2))))

dbWriteTable(datamart, "policy", pol_temp, overwrite = T)
rm(pol_temp)
```

...and then append every other file, repeating the code below for file.001 to file.007

```
tempfile <- tempfile()
save_object(object = "s3://thg_bucket/folder1/folder2/file.001", file = tempfile)
pol_temp <- read.csv(file = tempfile, sep = "|", quote = NULL) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ map_chr(.x, ~ str_sub(string = .x, start = 2, end = -2))))

dbWriteTable(datamart, "policy", pol_temp, append = T)
rm(pol_temp)
```

But, now there are 1,154 files to append in this way.  I tried the following but it isn't working.  Any correction to my code or an alternative approach is appreciated.  I also need the first file processed to be overwrite and all those after to be append.  Note 'Key' is the file name.

```
# Load policy files -------------------------------------------------------
path = "s3://thg_bucket/folder1/folder2/"
file.names <- data.table::rbindlist(get_bucket("thg_bucket", prefix = "folder1/folder2")) %>% 
  mutate(Key = str_sub(Key, 28, 37)) %>% 
  select(Key) %>% as.list()

# Read and Append Files
for(i in 1:length(file.names)){
  tempfile <- tempfile()
  save_object(object = paste0(path, file.names[i]), file = tempfile)
  pol_temp <- read.csv(file = tempfile, sep = "|", quote = NULL) %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ map_chr(.x, ~ str_sub(string = .x, start = 2, end = -2))))
  
  dbWriteTable(datamart, "policy", pol_temp, append = T)
  rm(pol_temp)  
}
```

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Are there errors or warnings? (What do they say?) Or does the table just not grow? Does the first iteration work, but then it fails? Or something else?

Comment: Error as follows ...  Error in parse_aws_s3_response(r, Sig, verbose = verbose) : 
  Bad Request (HTTP 400).
In addition: Warning message:
In structure(response, headers = h, class = "aws_error") :
  Calling 'structure(NULL, *)' is deprecated, as NULL cannot have attributes.
  Consider 'structure(list(), *)' instead.

Comment: Great, what iteration does the error occur on? (Check the value of `i`.). If it's 1, then your code has a problem. If it's greater than 1, then maybe that file has a problem. (And I'd suggest editing important details like this into your question so that new people wanting to help don't have to read the comments.)